# How to use htmlhint-loader with vuejs

Tags: webpack, vue.js, lint, vuejs2, htmllint

I am trying to setup html linting with my vuejs app, but I am not sure how to configure this correctly with my webpack config. I am currently trying with [htmlhint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlhint-loader). I installed it using this command:

```
npm install htmlhint-loader --save
```

And added following code in my **webpack.base.config**:

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'eslint',    // I'm already using eslint which works as expected
      include: projectRoot,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\(vue|html)$/,
      loader: 'htmlhint',
      include: projectRoot,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    ...
    ...
```

But this does not work, Let me know if anything else is also needed to make it work.

When I use this regex:

```
test: /(vue|html)$/,
```

I get following error:

> ERROR in ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html
>       Module parse failed: >/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/htmlhint-loader/index.js!/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/index.html Unexpected token (1:0)
>      You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>      SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
>          at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
>          at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
>          at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
>          at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/j/vue/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)

Comment: I think Regex for htmlhint is wrong - you are escaping capturing group.Try to put this `/(\.vue|\.html)$/` or this `/(vue|html)$/`

Comment: @BelminBedak I have tried these combinations,  I have edited the question with the error I get.

Comment: I'm not sure does htmlhint loader can watch single file vue components.Your can test it by setting just this `test: /\.html$/` and see would it throw any error.

Comment: It gives same error which I have added.

Comment: The comments are talking about `htmlhint-loader`, but the error says the `html-webpack-plugin`(which injects compiled js files to index.html) is failing to handle the html? Maybe check whether `index.html` has anything unusual?

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 everything works fine without `htmlhint-loader`.

Answer (score 1):

the `htmlhint-loader` can't check `vue -> template` code. but the [htmllint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmllint-loader) can work well.

Comment: Can you link more details about how you get this working? What does your webpack config look like? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need webpack-combine-loaders
then

```html
  var combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders')
  ...
  preLoaders: {
    html: combineLoaders([
      {
        loader: 'htmlhint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          rulesDir: 'rules/',
          'my-new-rule': 'this is pass to the rule (option)'
        }
      }
    ])
  }
  ...
```